# position div on bottom of document, not viewport

Tags: css

I want to position a div at the bottom of the document, but it is only going to the bottom of the viewport. How can I do this with CSS only? I tried `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` but that only puts it at the bottom of the viewport. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't have to position it for it to be at the end of the document. Just put the div at the end of the document in the markup.

Answer (score -1):

Use `position: relative;` on the parent container where you're gonna use the `position: absolute;`. See the snippet below:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 150vh;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

More on `position`s [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: I do not want the footer to be fixed, just something at the end of the document.

Comment: I've edited the snippet, check it if it's the behavior you are looking for.